# Abstract methods in Dart

Tags: inheritance, dart, dart-editor, abstract-methods

I'm implementing an inheritance hierarchy in which derived-class construction consists only of a call to the base-class constructor. The base-class constructor then calls method(s) implemented only in the derived-class.

I have a basic implementation, but DartEditor of course complains about the missing methods in the base class. How can I make it happy?

Edit: I hadn't yet ran any code before posting my question, and it turns out that method binding works in the manner one would expect:

```
void main() {
    new B();
}

abstract class A {
    A() {
        x();
        y();
    }
    x() => print('A.x');
    y() => print('A.y');
}

class B extends A {
    B() : super();

    @override
    x() => print('B.x');
}
```

The above code outputs the following, which is the desired behavior. `B`'s constructor calls `A`'s constructor which calls `x()`. But since there is an `x()` defined for `B`, this is the one called:

```
B.x
A.y
```

It interesting to note that, although `x()` is being called by `A`'s constructor, Dart somehow knows to call `B`'s `x()`. I presume this is because the call chain looks roughly like the following:

```
B() -> A() -> B::x()
```

At runtime, Dart inspects the call chain to determine to which object to bind `x()`.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing any concrete code that shows what you try to accomplish or any concrete error message.

Comment: This is normal object-oriented behavior. If you override a method in the derived class this method is called instead (called dynamic binding). You can explicitly call the method of the base class from the derived class like `super.x();` for example to reuse the base implementation.

Comment: Thanks. Even the part about the call to x() in A() binding to B::x()?

Comment: Sure. The code in `A.x()` was originally implemented in `A` but even when the code is invoked from code implemented in `A` the current instance is actually a `B` and therefore the method of `B` is called. (In my previous comment it should be "dynamic dispatch" instead of "dynamic binding")

Comment: Thanks. This has been very helpful. Is there a way to remove the implementation of x() in A altogether?

Comment: If you want to call or just reference `x()` from code in `A` it must exist. The minimum requirement if `A` is abstract is the declaration `x();` (see my first example in my answer). To work around this limitation you can add the `@proxy` annotation like I did in my answer in the 2nd example. This can have negative side-effects though (code bloat) when built to JS because this requires mirrors (reflection).

Comment: Would @proxy prevent *any* implementation in A? The code bloat thing is a good one to look out for...

Comment: `@proxy` doesn't prevent implementation, it just allows to call methods which are actually not there statically and indicates to the analyzer/VM that it should ignore their absence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your question I would expect code like this

```
void main() {
 new B();
}

abstract class A {
  A() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
  }
  a();
  b();
  c();
}

class B extends A {
  B() : super();

  @override
  a() => print('a');
  @override
  b() => print('b');
  @override
  c() => print('c');
}
```

Try in [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/307af8f60a2291c425ee)

From your comment about getting an error I expect you don't have the abstract method stubs in the base class.
Maybe this is what you are looking for

```
void main() {
 new B();
}

@proxy
abstract class A {
  A() {
    a();
    b();
    c();
  }
}

class B extends A {
  B() : super();

  a() => print('a');
  b() => print('b');
  c() => print('c');
}
```